# How Can I Retrieve the data from an XML file & display it in an HTML file, based on the user input?

Tags: html, xml, input, display

I have an XML file named `'users.xml'` that contains some data '(e.g. USERID, USERNAME, ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER)'. How can I access data for a particular 'User' from that XML file & display it using an HTML document, based on the user input. 
For example, when the user inputs the `'USERID'` as '1' & presses the `'Submit'` button, the HTML file will display all the information `(USERID, USERNAME, ADDRESS, PHONENUMBER)` for that user.

My `'users.xml'` file looks like as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<USERDATA>
  <USER>
    <USERID></USERID>
    <USERNAME></USERNAME>
    <ADDRESS></ADDRESS>
    <PHONENUMBER></PHONENUMBER>
  </USER>
</USERDATA>
```

Comment: You can parse use DOMParser in your JavaScript.  Can you show how you're getting that XML loaded and what not so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **jQuery**, Actually **jQuery** is base on the XML structure.
try 
`x = $('<USERDATA><USERID>xxx</USERID><USERNAME></USERNAME><ADDRESS></ADDRESS><PHONENUMBER></PHONENUMBER></USER></USERDATA>')`

and you can get the value by the jQuery api like `x.find('USERID').text()`

Here is a demo [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sinbar/xpvt214o/887551/)